# SQL - Get an average price of the last 7 days

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
timestamp | commodity | amount | price |
```

I am trying to get the weighted average of a commodity ,for each day from the last 7 days(In order to create a graph, c# program), I managed to create a query to get the weighted average:

```
SELECT SUM(price * amount),
       SUM(amount) 
  FROM [table_name] 
 WHERE (commodity = @commodity) 
   AND (timestamp >= @fromDate 
   AND timestamp <= @toDate);
```

So, I send this query 7 times, each time adding (-1) to the fromDate and toDate, to get the averages of last 7 days.

I would like to ask if there is a way to do this in 1 query, and if there is, if it can be implemented to get the same information of the last month.

Comment: you can use pivot table. check [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/pivot.php)

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use convert to date and do code as below:

```
  SELECT convert(date, timestamp) as [Dates], 
         SUM(price * amount),
         SUM(amount) 
    FROM [table_name] 
   WHERE (commodity = @commodity) 
     AND (timestamp >= @fromDate 
     AND timestamp <= @toDate)
GROUP BY convert(date, timestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to put a default value for dates with no records?

Comment: To generate dates I added another answer below

Answer (score 0):

you have to group by date

```
 SELECT SUM(price* amount),SUM(amount) FROM [table_name] WHERE (commodity = @commodity) AND (cast(timestamp  as date)>= @fromDate AND cast(timestamp  as date)<= @toDate)
Group By cast(timestamp  as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to group your data by date:

```
SELECT SUM(price * amount),SUM(amount) 
FROM [table_name] 
WHERE (commodity = @commodity) 
AND (timestamp >= @fromDate 
AND timestamp <= @toDate)
GROUP BY CAST(timestamp as DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate dates, you can use as below:

```
;with Datescte as (
      Select top (datediff(day, @fromDate, @toDate) +1) Dt = Dateadd(day, Row_Number() over (order by (Select null))-1, @fromDate) 
        from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
    ), cte2 as (
      SELECT convert(date, timestamp) as [Dates], 
             SUM(price * amount) as [Sum_Price_Amount],
             SUM(amount) as [Sum_Amount] 
        FROM [table_name] 
       WHERE (commodity = @commodity) 
         AND (timestamp >= @fromDate 
         AND timestamp <= @toDate)
    GROUP BY convert(date, timestamp)
    )
      Select Dt as [Dates] , Sum_Price_Amount, Sum_Amount 
        FROM Datescte d
        LEFT JOIN cte2 d2
          ON d.Dt = d2.Dates
```